# Decode UTF8 text

Tags: c#, utf-8, decode

I have string like "`CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=58=2D=54=65=73=74` ". I need to decode the last part of it which is  **`(58=2D=54=65=73=74)`** using c#. this string comes from contact file stored in amazon s3.  I try to use the following code but it is retrieve the same text

```
buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedText);
                                buffer = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"), buffer);
                                text = Deco.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have string encoded into UTF8

No, you cannot possibly have string encoded in UTF8. In .NET all strings are Unicode (UTF16) encoded.

What you are doing in your code example is converting the string (which don't forget is always Unicode) to an UTF-8 encoded byte array which is then converted into a `Windows-1252` byte array and finally you are attempting to convert this byte array to a string using ASCII encoding.

It's really not clear what you are trying to do here, but chances are that if you go through all those transformations from UTF-8 passing through Windows-1252 and finally to ASCII you might loose some characters which are not supported by the target encoding.

But the most important thing for you to remember is that encoding has meaning only when you are converting back and forth byte arrays. A byte array is encoded.

If you are attempting to fix some broken string that you got (`encodedText` variable) then you should fix the code which is retrieving this string. You cannot fix a broken string afterwards using some encodings.

---

UPDATE:

It seems that you are trying to parse `=58=2D=54=65=73=74` to the corresponding string value assuming that this is a HEX representation of an UTF-8 byte array.

Here's how you could do that:

```
string encodedText = "=58=2D=54=65=73=74";
encodedText = encodedText.Replace("=", string.Empty);
byte[] buffer = HexToByte(encodedText);
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

where the `HexToByte` function might look like this:

```
private static byte[] HexToByte(string hexString)
{
    byte[] returnBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < returnBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        returnBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return returnBytes;
}
```

Comment: but I get the string from out source

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh do the decoding properly when you construct your string from incoming data.

Comment: the encode text I get is : CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:= ** 58=2D=54=65=73=74 **

Comment: You should then fix the way you are retrieving this string.

Comment: here is the problem ! I cant find a way to retrieve it !

Comment: You haven't shown neither the code you have used to retrieve this string nor how and where is this value coming from. You haven't provided absolutely no details. Hard to help in this situation.

Comment: What's the value of the `encodedText` in your example? Is it `=58=2D=54=65=73=74`? Or is it the entire string you have shown in your updated question? I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: it is '=58=2D=54=65=73=74'

Comment: The OP should use an email library, not this buggy quoted printable decoder.